# SQL - Table Join and Pivot Query

Tags: sql, join, pivot

I need some advice. I'm trying to join two tables, but one has multiple rows for each academic course -- and I need all values for specific col's to be displayed after the join. I think this will include a pivot -- but that is a function I am unfamiliar with and I can't seem to get it to work. Here are the details. The join would be on Year_Code, Term_Code, and Course_Code.

Table1 = Course_List

- YEAR_CODE / TERM_CODE / COURSE_CODE
- 1920    /   SP      / Math_100
- 1920    /   SP      / Engl_100

Table2 = Inst_Load

- YEAR_CODE / TERM_CODE / COURSE_CODE / Instructor_ID / Load_Percent
- 1920    /   SP      / Math_100    /  0012         /  100
- 1920    /   SP      / Engl_100    /  0099         /  75
- 1920    /   SP      / Engl_100    /  0088         /  25

Output

- Year_Code / Term_Code / Course_Code / Inst1_ID / Inst1_Load_PCT /Inst2_ID / Inst2_Load_PCT
- 1920      /   SP      /   Math_100   /   0012  /         100
- 1920      /   SP      /   Engl_100   /   0099  /         75     /   0088 /    25

If possible, sort the selection of instructor load by highest percentage first? That would be nice too.

I appreciate the help. Trying to get a working code for this run. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this one. Cheers!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What database engine are you using? Sometimes, there are some built-in functions that allows you to get your expected output easier (ex: oracle `listagg`)

Comment: because there is additional information on either table by course that would be helpful to have in one place. This is a relational database I access using Sql management studio.

Comment: Then it's sql server... what version? (`SELECT @@version`)

Comment: Looks like SQL Server 2016.